# Creating a compute engine disk

Tags: python-2.7, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a compute engine disk using python. I am using source snap shot for creating the disk.

This is the code I am using for creation:

```
COMPUTE_URL_BASE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/'


def GenerateConfig(unused_context):
   """Creates the second virtual machine."""

resources = [{
  'name': 'MY_SNAP',
  'type': 'compute.beta.disk',
  'properties': {
      'zone': 'us-central1-a',
      'sizeGb': 10,
      'sourceSnapShot' :'global/snapshots/MY_SNAPSHOT', 
      }
  }
]
return {'resources': resources}
```

Here the disk is getting created, but snap shot is not getting attached with it.

I have created the snapshot through the google console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sourceSnapshot` should not have a capital 'S' in 'shot'. Try again with the correct capitalization.

Comment: Thank you ! me too found that mistake. i was so silly.